# Game Center "Player is not signed in"

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I made a new version of my app in iTunes Connect.
I upgraded the Info.plist bundle version & bundle versions, short, to the new version number.
I implemented Game Center leaderboads in Game Center.
Game center is shown as "Enabled" in iTunes Connect.
I attempt to authenticate & display leaderboards.

"The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center."

I tried disabling sandbox.
Same issue.

I realized I was signed into "Game Center" but my "Player" wasn't signed in. I signed in.

Same issue.

I disabling sandbox, same issue.

Signing out of Gamecenter, signing in again.

Same issue.

iOS 8, iPhone 5, latest Xcode, Objective-C.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Want free points? Answer this: Delete the app, restart Xcode, sacrifice a Goat Simulator & try again.

Comment: Did you enable Game Center in *both* places in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled in both spots in Settings & iTunes Connect new build.